# Getting two pipelines to communicate to deploy on Beanstalk dev-env and then run integration tests with NewMan before releasing on prod-env

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

## What we already have (and works)

Two different pipelines:

1. We are pulling our SpringBoot backend code from CodeCommit repo, running `mvn clean compile test`, and upon success, deploying on the Elastic Beanstalk `dev` environment (which uses the Tomcat/Java8 config).
2. We have another repo on CodeCommit which contains the PostMan collection to be run by NewMan for the integration tests. Its urls point to the `dev` endpoints. CodePipeline is also used to pull the source code and then install and run NewMan through shell commands in the Build phase. The `buildspec.yml` file used by CodeBuild is configured with `nodejs: 10` as its `runtime-versions`. However, this pipeline needs to be triggered manually to test the application.

## What we are missing

We now want to understand how it would be possible to:

- trigger our "IntegrationTestsPipeline" after a successful deployment on the `dev` environment
- deploy (upon success of all the integration tests) on the `prod` environment the application that is now on the `dev` environment

We are having trouble understanding how two pipelines can communicate likeso (or how to merge both into a single pipeline: even better).

## Precision

I am not the person that had initially set up the whole infrastructure on AWS.

Somehow, despite our application being deployed on Beanstalk, the "Deploy" phase references CloudFormation as its Provider. The two Actions listed in that phase are `GenerateChangeSet` and `ExecuteChangeSet`. I'm not sure I understand why that is (nor how it works exactly): I would have thought that simply using Beanstalk as the Provider for the Deploy phase would have been easier.

Answer (score 1):

The basic API to start a Pipeline is "StartPipelineExecution". You can have a Lambda invoke action [0] in your first pipeline and call the API StartPipelineExecution [1] from the Lambda with the pipeline name (of second pipeline) to start the pipeline. Another option is to have a CodeBuild action and call the 'start-pipeline-execution' [2] using aws cli.

For your query regarding GenerateChangeSet, and ExecuteChangeSet, it is a good practise, since when you generate a ChangeSet, it gives you the opportunity to see what changes CloudFormation will make before actually applying/executing those changes.

Ref:

[0]
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_StartPipelineExecution.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/start-pipeline-execution.html

Comment: Interesting. I ended up learning about CloudWatch Events and [implementing a Rule to trigger my 2nd Pipeline when a designated Stage ends in my 1st Pipeline](https://pastebin.com/vePtarZ0), but that only solved my "communication" problem. Now, based on your intervention, if I understood properly, using a Beanstalk Provider for a deployment as an Action is equivalent to using the `GenerateChangeSet` and `ExecuteChangeSet` Actions through the CloudFormation Provider, except I would not be able to review the changes to be (that is, a `ManualApproval` could be inserted in between those 2 Actions)?

Comment: Now, I realize it would be really nice to figure out how I could get a `SUCCEEDED` state on my 2nd Pipeline to `Accept` a `ManualApproval` (or some other kind of "wait for confirmation" Action) on the 1st Pipeline so that a person would not need to go look at the state of that 2nd Pipeline to know that the Integration Tests have passed.

Comment: Concerning your answer, another question that comes to my mind is: what would then be the differences between using the `Lambda` vs using the `CloudWatch Events Rules` ?